# How to assign MongoDB document data into generic list in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have my data in MongoDB that looks like this:

```
_id:ObjectId("59d33718050bad45ec6e6f53")
Timestamp:2017-10-03 15:07:04.145
ID:"915110933730439169"
Content:"Turn on the light"
DateCreated:2017-05-12 00:00:00.000
UserID:"862903658828017666"
Username:"Johnny"
```

And I only need the "Content" data in one of my classes, and I have to assign those content into a generic list. (I have no idea of how much the data would be). So I look around online and I have done the Deserialization of the Bson object into class, but then I have no idea how to assign only "content" inside the list because only the "content" will work on other purposes in this class.

Below are my code of this class:

```
class Analysis
{
    public static void RetrieveData()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var database = client.GetDatabase("TrainData");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Sample1");

        List<string> streamdata = new List<string>();

        var filter = new BsonDocument();
        var cursor = collection.FindAsync(filter).Result;
        cursor.ForEachAsync(batch =>
        {
            streamdata.Add(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<string>(batch));
        });

    }

public class StreamData
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

May I know where did I missing or what else I have to added in order to let me insert the "content" into the generic list? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use projection to get the "Content" data only.

```
        var data = collection.Aggregate().Project<BsonDocument>(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude(f => f["_id"]).Include(f => f["Content"])).ToList();

        List<string> streamdata = new List<string>();

        foreach(var d in data)
        {
            streamdata.Add(d["Content"].AsString);
        }
```

Comment: It works!!! I get to display all the content! Thank you so much I've been searching around for one whole day for this solution!!!